# What is the difference between these JavaScript anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//anonymous 1
(function(){
    $('something').first().addClass("anything");
});

//anonymous 2
(function(){
    $('something').first().addClass("anything");
})();
```

What is the actual and practical difference between these two?

```
(function(){

});
```

and

```
(function(){

})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is never called, it's just a function

```
(function(){

}); // never called
```

The second one adds the parentheses at the end, which calls the function immediately, which is why it's called an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
(function(){

})(); // called now
```